# Android ffmpeg with libx264 - undefined references

Tags: android, ffmpeg, undefined-reference, libx264

I'm building ffmpeg for Android with libx264 using [appunite's project](https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg) under Ubuntu 15.10. I've build it without libx264 properly, but adding the library keep giving me `undefined reference to 'x264_picture_init'` and multiple other similar errors. I tried variety of possible solutions from mailing lists/other SO questions, but still nothing helps me solving the problem.

I have removed ffmpeg/libx264/libx264-dev packages to avoid possible duplicate libraries in the system. I've got the libx264.a library in ffmpeg-build/ARCH/lib, where the other built libraries lives. Also I don't think this is caused by header file not matching the library, because the only x264.h header in the system is the one used for the library building.

Here is my build_android.sh.

```
set -x

if [ "$ANDROID_NDK_HOME" = "" ]; then
    echo ANDROID_NDK_HOME variable not set, exiting
    echo "Use: export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=/your/path/to/android-ndk"
    exit 1
fi

# Get the newest arm-linux-androideabi version
if [ -z "$COMPILATOR_VERSION" ]; then
    DIRECTORIES=$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-*
    for i in $DIRECTORIES; do
        PROPOSED_NAME=${i#*$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-}
        if [[ $PROPOSED_NAME =~ ^[0-9\.]+$ ]] ; then
            echo "Available compilator version: $PROPOSED_NAME"
            COMPILATOR_VERSION=$PROPOSED_NAME
        fi
    done
fi

if [ -z "$COMPILATOR_VERSION" ]; then
    echo "Could not find compilator"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d $ANDROID_NDK_HOME/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-$COMPILATOR_VERSION ]; then
    echo $ANDROID_NDK_HOME/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-$COMPILATOR_VERSION does not exist
    exit 1
fi
echo "Using compilator version: $COMPILATOR_VERSION"

OS_ARCH=`basename $ANDROID_NDK_HOME/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-$COMPILATOR_VERSION/prebuilt/*`
echo "Using architecture: $OS_ARCH"


function setup_paths
{
    export PLATFORM=$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/platforms/$PLATFORM_VERSION/arch-$ARCH/
    if [ ! -d $PLATFORM ]; then
        echo $PLATFORM does not exist
        exit 1
    fi
    echo "Using platform: $PLATFORM"
    export PATH=${PATH}:$PREBUILT/bin/
    export CROSS_COMPILE=$PREBUILT/bin/$EABIARCH-
    export CFLAGS=$OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS
    export CPPFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
    export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
    export CXXFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
    export CXX="${CROSS_COMPILE}g++ --sysroot=$PLATFORM"
    export AS="${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc --sysroot=$PLATFORM"
    export CC="${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc --sysroot=$PLATFORM"
    export PKG_CONFIG="${CROSS_COMPILE}pkg-config"
    export LD="${CROSS_COMPILE}ld"
    export NM="${CROSS_COMPILE}nm"
    export STRIP="${CROSS_COMPILE}strip"
    export RANLIB="${CROSS_COMPILE}ranlib"
    export AR="${CROSS_COMPILE}ar"
    export LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib -nostdlib -lc -lm -ldl -llog"
    export PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=$PREFIX/lib/pkgconfig/
    export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PREFIX/lib/pkgconfig/

    if [ ! -f "${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc" ]; then
        echo "Gcc does not exists in path: ${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc"
        exit 1;
    fi

    if [ ! -f "${PKG_CONFIG}" ]; then
        echo "Pkg config does not exists in path: ${PKG_CONFIG} - Probably BUG in NDK but..."
        set +e
        SYS_PKG_CONFIG=$(which pkg-config)
        if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "This system does not contain system pkg-config, so we can do anything"
            exit 1
        fi
        set -e
        cat > $PKG_CONFIG << EOF
#!/bin/bash
pkg-config \$*
EOF
        chmod u+x $PKG_CONFIG
        echo "Because we have local pkg-config we will create it in ${PKG_CONFIG} directory using ${SYS_PKG_CONFIG}"
    fi
}

function build_x264
{
    echo "Starting build x264 for $ARCH"
    cd x264
    ./configure --prefix=$PREFIX --host=$ARCH-linux --enable-static --disable-shared --enable-pic --disable-cli $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG

    make clean
    make -j4 install
    make clean
    cd ..
    echo "FINISHED x264 for $ARCH"
}

function build_amr
{
    echo "Starting build amr for $ARCH"
    cd vo-amrwbenc
    ./configure \
        --prefix=$PREFIX \
        --host=$ARCH-linux \
        --disable-dependency-tracking \
        --disable-shared \
        --enable-static \
        --with-pic \
        $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG

    make clean
    make -j4 install
    make clean
    cd ..
    echo "FINISHED amr for $ARCH"
}

function build_aac
{
    echo "Starting build aac for $ARCH"
    cd vo-aacenc
    ./configure \
        --prefix=$PREFIX \
        --host=$ARCH-linux \
        --disable-dependency-tracking \
        --disable-shared \
        --enable-static \
        --with-pic \
        $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG

    make clean
    make -j4 install
    make clean
    cd ..
    echo "FINISHED aac for $ARCH"
}
function build_freetype2
{
    echo "Starting build freetype2 for $ARCH"
    cd freetype2
    ./configure \
        --prefix=$PREFIX \
        --host=$ARCH-linux \
        --disable-dependency-tracking \
        --disable-shared \
        --enable-static \
        --with-pic \
        $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG

    make clean
    make -j4 install
    make clean
    cd ..
    echo "FINISHED freetype2 for $ARCH"
}

function build_ass
{
    echo "Starting build ass for $ARCH"
    cd libass
    ./configure \
        --prefix=$PREFIX \
        --host=$ARCH-linux \
        --disable-fontconfig \
        --disable-dependency-tracking \
        --disable-shared \
        --enable-static \
        --with-pic \
        $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG

    make clean
    make V=1 -j4 install
    make clean
    cd ..
    echo "FINISHED ass for $ARCH"
}
function build_fribidi
{
    echo "Starting build fribidi for $ARCH"
    cd fribidi
    ./configure \
        --prefix=$PREFIX \
        --host=$ARCH-linux \
        --disable-bin \
        --disable-dependency-tracking \
        --disable-shared \
        --enable-static \
        --with-pic \
        $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG

    make clean
    make -j4 install
    make clean
    cd ..
    echo "FINISHED fribidi for $ARCH"
}
function build_ffmpeg
{
    echo "Starting build ffmpeg for $ARCH"
    cd ffmpeg
    ./configure --target-os=linux \
        --prefix=$PREFIX \
        --enable-cross-compile \
        --extra-libs="-lgcc -L$PREFIX/lib/libx264.a" \
        --arch=$ARCH \
        --cc=$CC \
        --cross-prefix=$CROSS_COMPILE \
        --nm=$NM \
        --sysroot=$PLATFORM \
        --extra-cflags=" -O3 -fpic -DANDROID -DHAVE_SYS_UIO_H=1 -Dipv6mr_interface=ipv6mr_ifindex -fasm -Wno-psabi -fno-short-enums  -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=300 $OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS" \
        --disable-shared \
        --enable-static \
        --enable-runtime-cpudetect \
        --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
        --extra-ldflags="-Wl,-rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib  -nostdlib -lc -lm -ldl -llog -L$PREFIX/lib" \
        --extra-cflags="-I$PREFIX/include" \
        --disable-everything \
        --enable-gpl \
        --enable-pthreads \
        --enable-libass \
        --enable-libvo-aacenc \
        --enable-libvo-amrwbenc \
        --enable-hwaccel=h264_vaapi \
        --enable-hwaccel=h264_vaapi \
        --enable-hwaccel=h264_dxva2 \
        --enable-hwaccel=mpeg4_vaapi \
        --enable-libx264 \
        --enable-demuxer=mov \
        --enable-demuxer=h264 \
        --enable-muxer=h264 \
        --enable-demuxer=mpegvideo \
        --enable-demuxer=h263 \
        --enable-demuxer=mpegps \
        --enable-demuxer=mjpeg \
        --enable-demuxer=rtsp \
        --enable-demuxer=rtp \
        --enable-demuxer=hls \
        --enable-demuxer=matroska \
        --enable-muxer=rtsp \
        --enable-muxer=mp4 \
        --enable-muxer=mov \
        --enable-muxer=mjpeg \
        --enable-muxer=matroska \
        --enable-protocol=crypto \
        --enable-protocol=jni \
        --enable-protocol=file \
        --enable-protocol=rtp \
        --enable-protocol=tcp \
        --enable-protocol=udp \
        --enable-protocol=applehttp \
        --enable-protocol=hls \
        --enable-protocol=http \
        --enable-decoder=xsub \
        --enable-decoder=jacosub \
        --enable-decoder=dvdsub \
        --enable-decoder=dvbsub \
        --enable-decoder=subviewer \
        --enable-decoder=rawvideo \
        --enable-encoder=rawvideo \
        --enable-decoder=mjpeg \
        --enable-encoder=mjpeg \
        --enable-decoder=h263 \
        --enable-decoder=mpeg4 \
        --enable-encoder=mpeg4 \
        --enable-decoder=h264 \
        --enable-encoder=h264 \
        --enable-decoder=aac \
        --enable-encoder=aac \
        --enable-parser=h264 \
        --enable-encoder=mp2 \
        --enable-decoder=mp2 \
        --enable-encoder=libvo_amrwbenc \
        --enable-decoder=amrwb \
        --enable-muxer=mp2 \
        --enable-bsfs \
        --enable-decoders \
        --enable-encoders \
        --enable-parsers \
        --enable-hwaccels \
        --enable-muxers \
        --enable-avformat \
        --enable-avcodec \
        --enable-avresample \
        --enable-zlib \
        --disable-doc \
        --disable-ffplay \
        --disable-ffmpeg \
        --disable-ffplay \
        --disable-ffprobe \
        --disable-ffserver \
        --enable-avfilter \
        --disable-avdevice \
        --disable-opencl \
        --enable-nonfree \
        --enable-version3 \
        --enable-memalign-hack \
        --enable-asm \
        $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
    make clean
    make -j4 install
    make clean

    cd ..
    echo "FINISHED ffmpeg for $ARCH"
}

function build_one {
    echo "Starting build one for $ARCH"
    cd ffmpeg
    ${LD} -rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PREFIX/lib  -soname $SONAME -shared -nostdlib -Bsymbolic --whole-archive --no-undefined -o $OUT_LIBRARY -lavformat -lavcodec -lavresample -lavutil -lswresample -lavfilter -lass -lfreetype -lfribidi -lswscale -lvo-aacenc -lvo-amrwbenc -lc -lm -lz -ldl -llog --dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker -zmuldefs $PREBUILT/lib/gcc/$EABIARCH/$COMPILATOR_VERSION/libgcc.a
    cd ..
    echo "FINISHED one for $ARCH"
}

# enable additional architectures later on

#arm v5
#EABIARCH=arm-linux-androideabi
#ARCH=arm
#CPU=armv5
#OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-marm -march=$CPU"
#PREFIX=$(pwd)/ffmpeg-build/armeabi
#OUT_LIBRARY=$PREFIX/libffmpeg.so
#ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=
#SONAME=libffmpeg.so
#PREBUILT=$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-$COMPILATOR_VERSION/prebuilt/$OS_ARCH
#PLATFORM_VERSION=android-5
#setup_paths
#build_amr
#build_aac
#build_fribidi
#build_freetype2
#build_ass
#build_ffmpeg
#build_one

#x86
#EABIARCH=i686-linux-android
#ARCH=x86
#OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-m32"
#PREFIX=$(pwd)/ffmpeg-build/x86
#OUT_LIBRARY=$PREFIX/libffmpeg.so
#ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=--disable-asm
#SONAME=libffmpeg.so
#PREBUILT=$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/toolchains/x86-$COMPILATOR_VERSION/prebuilt/$OS_ARCH
#PLATFORM_VERSION=android-9
#setup_paths
#build_amr
#build_aac
#build_fribidi
#build_freetype2
#build_ass
#build_ffmpeg
#build_one

#mips
#EABIARCH=mipsel-linux-android
#ARCH=mips
#OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-EL -march=mips32 -mips32 -mhard-float"
#PREFIX=$(pwd)/ffmpeg-build/mips
#OUT_LIBRARY=$PREFIX/libffmpeg.so
#ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG="--disable-mips32r2"
#SONAME=libffmpeg.so
#PREBUILT=$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/toolchains/mipsel-linux-android-$COMPILATOR_VERSION/prebuilt/$OS_ARCH
#PLATFORM_VERSION=android-9
#setup_paths
#build_amr
#build_aac
#build_fribidi
#build_freetype2
#build_ass
#build_ffmpeg
#build_one

#arm v7vfpv3
EABIARCH=arm-linux-androideabi
ARCH=arm
CPU=armv7-a
OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -marm -march=$CPU "
PREFIX=$(pwd)/ffmpeg-build/armeabi-v7a
OUT_LIBRARY=$PREFIX/libffmpeg.so
ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=
SONAME=libffmpeg.so
PREBUILT=$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-$COMPILATOR_VERSION/prebuilt/$OS_ARCH
PLATFORM_VERSION=android-5
setup_paths
build_x264
build_amr
build_aac
build_fribidi
build_freetype2
build_ass
build_ffmpeg
build_one

#arm v7 + neon (neon also include vfpv3-32)
EABIARCH=arm-linux-androideabi
ARCH=arm
CPU=armv7-a
OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -marm -march=$CPU -mtune=cortex-a8 -mthumb -D__thumb__ "
PREFIX=$(pwd)/ffmpeg-build/armeabi-v7a-neon
OUT_LIBRARY=../ffmpeg-build/armeabi-v7a/libffmpeg-neon.so
ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=--enable-neon
SONAME=libffmpeg-neon.so
PREBUILT=$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-$COMPILATOR_VERSION/prebuilt/$OS_ARCH
PLATFORM_VERSION=android-9
setup_paths
build_x264
build_amr
build_aac
build_fribidi
build_freetype2
build_ass
build_ffmpeg
build_one


echo "BUILD SUCCESS"
```

I've disabled the non-arm architectures for the time being. If there is any other information I can provide to help finding the problem, I will be happy to do so.

I'm wondering if the issue may be caused by something missing in the script, namely in build_one part, tho I tried to indicate the libx264.a  directly in --extra-ldflags, without success.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that all steps until `build_one` passed successfully?

Comment: @AlexCohn yes, that is correct, in terms of errors. Build process stops with `undefined references` in `build_one` stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **build-one** function, the command

> ${LD} -rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PREFIX/lib  -soname $SONAME -shared -nostdlib -Bsymbolic --whole-archive --no-undefined -o $OUT_LIBRARY -lavformat -lavcodec -lavresample -lavutil -lswresample -lavfilter -lass -lfreetype -lfribidi -lswscale -lvo-aacenc -lvo-amrwbenc -lc -lm -lz -ldl -llog --dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker -zmuldefs $PREBUILT/lib/gcc/$EABIARCH/$COMPILATOR_VERSION/libgcc.a

should also use **-llx264**.

You mentioned that this library is already placed in **$PLATFORM/lib**. With **--whole-archive**, the order of libraries should not matter, but to be on the safe side, place this enchantment immediately after **-lavcodec**. If you still have some link errors, the order of libraries may undergo fine tuning.

### Edit

As **Krzysztof Kansy** discovered, the library files should be listed explicitly, not with `-l` notation.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Indeed, I missed adding -lx264, but I had to provide the library names in other way than i thought. Instead of -lx264, it had to be $Prefix/lib/libx264.a, so for some reason only full paths worked. The same applies to libavcodec etc. Anyway, you showed me the righ direction and the build works. Thanks!

Comment: Now I understand, to produce whole archive, a list of **`-l`** is not good.